# Fast Comparing of the Volume of Simplices Defined by Sidelengths

Tags: algorithms, discrete-geometry, determinants

I have a problem, that requires sorting a set of simplices, that are defined via their sidelengths, according to volume; the value of the individual volumes isn't relevant in my problem.

> **Question:**
>
> are there faster methods of comparing the volumes of two simplices (that are defined via their sidelengths), than comparing the absolute values of their [Cayley Menger determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry_problem#Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinants)?
>
> - if no, where can I find details about the initial proof?
> - if yes, what are relevant algorithms for that problem?

Comment: Seems unlikely there is anything better than the determinant calculation. But at least there has been some work on optimizing the calculation: [Kahan: Volume of a Tetrahedron PDF download](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/VtetLang.pdf).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I also don't put much hope in the existence of something better, and I guess I will have to accept an $O(n^5)$ time complexity for the problem I am trying to solve (canonical ordering of points on basis of distance measurements). Thanks for the pointer to Kahan's paper anyways; that reduces the risk of wrong ordering because of numeric issues..